# Limit Results from mysql using if statement

Tags: mysql, limit

I've got if statement code that works for the where clause of mysql query, but not for the limit statement. Could someone please help me to get this to work or a similar alternative? It gives me an expected result Boolean error.

I'm trying to use the if statement to find out if the $limit variable has any value except OFF. If it does, then limit the results of the mysql query by whatever number, 20 in this case. I'm not sure if that helps.

I honestly don't know if this the correct way of doing this.

```
$limit='20'; or whatever number

IF('$limit'<>'OFF',LIMIT $limit,'$limit'=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could avoid if  using a ternary operator

```
$limit='20'; or whatever number


$limit_result = ($limit<>'OFF' ? $limit : 0);
```